# unable to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Tags: android

I'm new in android and I setup android studio 3.4.1. With proxy settings I can download necessary android SDK files but in build project I have below error

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

in settings Offline work is unchecked and this is my Top-level build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
                 url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my app build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I searched a lot and just append *maven.google.com* to all project scope in top-build file. after this change when I build project android studio trying to download the necessary file to resolve but nothings changed
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post your app build gradle file

Comment: Checking the issue

Comment: Can you explain your meaning?

Comment: Try to add the `maven {
                 url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }` to the first `repositories` block. If the problem still persisted, reboot your device then check if your Android Studion internet access is blocked or not by your system or Anti Virus.

Comment: Try adding this to your gradle.properties file -
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: I tried all you said but still no working. Android Studio detect may internet connection firewall is disabled and don't have any anti virus

Comment: Any idea friends? :(